# Blender 2.8 Cycles All Materials Same Color As Viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I don't remember changing any settings that I don't know what are for. The color of all materials is exactly the same as the one of the viewport background, ignoring roughness etc. This also occurs in final render. Eevee works fine, problem is only when using Cycles.

What have I done wrong? Any solutions?

[image: Viewport screenshot:]

Comment: I had the same issue, but because of something different. I did not realize I had Pause Preview enabled. Now I know that option exists too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**
At some point I accidentally moved my objects to background layer. I had the transparent background turned on, so they got invisible. Moving them back to foreground solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question. You don't have to write SOLVED. In this site the way to mark an answer as correct is tp accept it using the checkmark. Please read: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few probable reasons why this is occurring.

1. If you go under the Object Data tab in the Properties panel, look for a material RGB color wheel/box. Check to see if the stored color there  matches your object's color.
2. Your Material may be causing this effect. You usually have to edit your materials so that the render engine can impemebt them properly. Make sure there are no problem with your node/material structure when using Cycles.
3. Check the "Draw Type" check boxes in the Object tab in the Properties panel. One of these may be causing this u expected result. Try playing around with them and see what happens.

Hope this helps.